# Existe alguma alternativa para o system('cls') no PHP Console?

Tags: php, windows, console

Estou usando PHP (5.7) no console (Windows 10), porém não estou conseguindo limpar a tela. Dou um `system('cls')` e só aparece um quadradinho com um ponto de interrogação, sem limpar a tela.

[image: Problema com cls]

Já fiz da seguinte forma:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) echo "\r\n";
```

Limpa, mas a mensagem seguinte fica lá em baixo no console e demora a limpar, na verdade ele só pula as linhas, e eu não queria que isso acontecesse. o `system('cls')` realmente limpa o console.

Existe alguma alternativa ou um meio de resolver este problema?

Comment: CTRL + L não limpa?

Comment: Ele quer chamar a partir do script @RafaelAcioly

Comment: `system('clear');`, ja tentou?

Comment: system('clear'); dá como comando não reconhecido. Acredito que este seja apenas para Linux

Comment: É um negócio chato de resolver e de fato não fica portátil nem entre versões do mesmo OS. Mas isso é consequência de usar o PHP de uma maneira que ele não foi concebido para ser usado, então tem dessas dificuldades mesmo. As vezes coisinhas simples ficam impossíveis nesses cenários.

Comment: Editei sua pergunta incluindo as informações que você comentou na minha pergunta Dando uma lida na Internet parece que bastante gente teve esse problema. Na teoria o Windows 10 deveria ter resolvido isso. Usar o PowerShell é uma opção no seu caso?

Comment: Experimente `system('cmd /c cls')`

Comment: Funcionou! LS_dev

Comment: WallaceMagalhães, eu vi que voce trocou a resposta aceita do LS_Dev para a do Daniel. Ambas as respostas funcionaram no seu ambiente? A do Daniel se encaixou melhor?

Comment: Exatamente, a do Daniel se encaixou melhor.

Comment: Testei todas respostas e de fato nenhuma delas resolve o que é pedido no titulo, o uso de "\r" retorna o cursor para o começo da linha o que faz ela ser sobrescrita, mas isso não é `cls` (limpar tela) é apenas a linha atual.

Comment: Se quiser somente substituir a linha no windows acrescente "\r" no começo da mensagem sem colocar "\n" no final Ex. echo("\r Seu texto 1") - echo("\r Seu texto 2") etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os códigos de todas as outras respostas não funcionaram no meu ambiente:

Windows 10, PHP7 e versões anteriores até a versão 5.3.6.

De todas as resposta que se encontra na internet, a mais bizarra é fazer dezenas de quebras de linha. É como varrer sujeira para debaixo do tapete.

Resumindo, ao final dos testes, concluí que sob Windows 10, independente da versão do PHP, basta imprimir `"\r"` entre aspas. Outros comandos usados com a função `chr()` ou escrever caracteres de escape do CMD, parece não surtir efeito algum.

## Teste com a função [chr()](http://php.net/chr)

```
<?php
echo time()."\r";
chr(27);
sleep(1);
echo time();
```

Coloquei o `sleep(1)` para testar. Não é necessário estar aí.

É importante que ao final de cada linha impressa tenha um retorno `\r` entre aspas duplas.

O script original foi adaptado dessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424357/1685571

Nessa mesma resposta, foi importante o comentário do [@recursion.ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1465011/recursion-ninja) pois o código original usa `\n`, o qual não funcionou. Porém, após trocar por `\r` funcionou perfeitamente.

Também reduzi todo o código para simplificar e ficar mais claro onde está a "mágica". Removi o construtor `echo` pois não faz sentido usar. O uso do echo faz com que sejam impressos aqueles símbolos estranhos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao executar foi exibido `1484622554`. Em seguida, foi substituído por `1484622555` e por fim, `1484622556`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aquele `^Z` é devido ao `ENTER, CTRL + Z, ENTER` para poder executar o script.

Dependendo da versão do Windows, é `CTRL + D`.

A partir dessa lógica, é possível deixar mais dinâmico criando uma espécie de wraper para os scripts a ser executados. Um exemplo de "wraper" está na resposta original. Apenas precisa remover pontos desnecessários e fazer alguns ajustes. Os quais estão aqui descritos.

## Curiosidades:

Por curiosidade, testei se é realmente a função chr() que faz a limpeza da linha. Modifiquei o valor do parâmetro para qualquer outro valor e deu o mesmo resultado. Então experimentei remover a função e para minha surpresa, funcionou como se espera.

```
<?php
echo time()."a\r";
//chr(0);
//sleep(1);
echo time()."b\r";
//chr(0);
//sleep(1);
echo time()."c";
```

Nesse teste, parece que `chr()` não faz diferença alguma. Imprimiu o último valor concatenado com "c" sem imprimir os dois anteriores.

Se delimitar o `\r` com aspa simples, imprime as três linhas concatenadas.

Com esse teste podemos ver que basta apenas imprimir `"\r"` entre aspas duplas.

Ao menos isso funciona no Windows 10.

Erros comuns presentes em outras respostas é que praticamente todos mandam imprimir o resultado de um construtor. Isso não faz sentido e acarreta na impressão de símbolos estranhos como esse `�`.

Invocar o `cmd /c cls` pela função `exec()` também não faz sentido pois o `cls` será executado numa outra instância do *CMD*. Instância essa que está vazia e não acessível visualmente, ou seja, está limpando o vazio invisível. rsrs

## Libraries do PHP

No PHP existe uma função específica para realizar a função do `clear/cls`. A função é [ncurses_clear()](http://php.net/ncurses_clear).

Essa função pertence a library [NCurses](http://php.net/ncurses) e está disponível para sistemas Linux. Contudo é uma library experimental e o último build é de 2012. Normalmente não se confia em libraries desse tipo e o próprio manual do PHP adverte. Mas nada impede que alguém dê continuidade. Basta ler o código fonte, aprimorar e compilar.

Comment: Daniel, as outras respostas funcionam caso [escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx) estejam habilitados. Veja que o próprio OP marcou uma resposta como correta. Adicionalmente posso confirmar que escape sequences funcionaram corretamente para mim no PowerShell. Dito iss, Infelizmente existem incompatibilidades entre o interprador PHP e o cmd como colocado pelo Bacco.  Em algumas soluções o pessoal é obrigado a apelar para loops com `\r\n` :(

Answer (score 11):

Tente o seguinte:

```
echo chr(27).chr(91).'H'.chr(27).chr(91).'J'; // ^[H^[J
```

**Fonte:** [PHP clear terminal screen](http://pank.org/blog/2011/02/php-clear-terminal-screen.html)

Comment: Não deu. O resultado é mais ou menos como o do system('cls'): um "quadradinho" estranho como se fosse um caractere desconhecido.

Comment: Que estranho, testei aqui no Windows 10 e funcionou. 
Não seria algo no seu ambiente? Atualize a pergunta com as versões do PHP, Windows, configurações relevantes de ambiente e um printscreen do carácter de controle se puder. Ao abrir um *command prompt* e digitar `cls` ou dar `echo` [no código de escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx) acima a tela limpa?

Comment: Então, uso PHP 5.6, Windows 10. Acontece isso: http://imgur.com/a/O7jRo. Deve ser algum problema da versão, vou testar com o PHP 7 e edito aqui com o resultado.

Answer (score 7):

`cls` não é um executável Windows, mas sim um comando da interpretador de comandos (`cmd.exe` no Windows 7, ...).

Assim, para o poder executar deve-se invocar o interpretador de comandos:

```
cmd.exe /c cls
```

O argumento `/c` força o interpretador a fechar após a execução do comando.

Comment: Não funcionou. Parece uma ótima resposta, mas no `Windows 8.1` e `php 5.6` não tive o resultado esperado, veja criei este script para teste: http://pastebin.com/raw/rXX55LJN então chamei assim no cmd: php meuscript.php mas ele não limpou a tela **https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6N1y.jpg** e se uso `system` no lugar de `exec` é mostrado o caractere `♀`, veja: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYwee.png**

Answer (score 4):

Você pode tentar assim:

```
<?php
echo "Mensagem antes de limpar\n";

echo "\033[2J\033[1;1H";

echo "Mensagem depois de limpar\n";
?>
```

Onde o *ANSI* `\033[2J` limpa de fato a tela, mas o seu complementar `\033[1;1H` redefine o início da 'próxima tela', você pode testar só com `\033[2J`, mas verá que o texto imprimido após esse `echo` estará um pouco a baixo do inicio da janela do *prompt*.

Essa solução também funciona no terminal do *Linux*, apenas no *Power Shell* que testei e não funcionou.

O resultado será esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:
`popen('cls || clear','w');`

Vai funcionar, pois as || significa "ou" lembra em c? Pois é, outra coisa o comando cls não funciona no Linux deve se usar clear. Tente e e avise se funcionou!

Answer (score -2):

Infelizmente, o PHP 8.0.2 não tem uma função para fazer isso. No entanto, se você deseja apenas limpar o console, tente isto: print ("\ 033 [2J \ 033 [; H");
ou popen('cls','w');
Funciona no php 8.0.2. É o mesmo que o system('cls') usando programação em linguagem c
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acabei confundindo pois publiquei essa mesma reposta em outras comunidades. Vou colocar a resposta em português.